# Run one Jquery Script independently for each <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following question:

I am working on a JQuery script that turns some HTML into a "Slider". No problem so far, everything's working smoothly.

The thing is is, if I want to run two or more "sliders" at the same time, of course they all "act" the same.

If I want them to act differently at the same time, can I "add" the script several times in the HTML-Code (, or do I have to add a ".each()" function, to the script?

HTML-Code:

```
<div id="galleria1" interval="1000">
            <a href="#" class="show" >
                <img width="640" height="450" rel="Slider-Image"src="a.jpg" />
            </a>
            ...
</div>

<div id="galleria2" interval="1000">
            <a href="#" class="show" >
                <img width="640" height="450" rel="Slider-Image"src="b.jpg" />
            </a>
            ...
</div>
```

Would be cool of any of you knows a solution to this!

Thanks, Mario.

EDIT:

Here the Script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //checks if page is completely loaded
    slideshow();
});


function slideshow()
{
    //Sets all pictures opacity to 0
    $('#galleria a').css({opacity:0.0});
    //Sets the first picture's opacity to 1
    $('#galleria a:first').css({opacity:1.0});
    //Calls the gallery() function to run the slideshow, number gives time till next 'slide' im milliseconds
    setInterval('nextPicture()', 1000);
}

function nextPicture()
{
    //If no image hast the class 'show', takes the first picture
    var current = ($('#galleria a.show')? $('#galleria a.show') : $('#galleria a:first'));
    //Get next image, if reached the end of slideshow, starts from the begining
    var next = ((current.next().length == 0) ? $('#galleria a:first') : current.next()); 
    //Runs Animation and makes next picture visible, number gives fade in time
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('show')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
    //Hides last picture
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0},1000)
        .removeClass('show');
}
```

-> used the same id="galleria" for both so far. (already changed this in the html above)

Thanks for the answers so far!

Comment: If you post the JavaScript code too it might be possible to give a much more specific answer.

Comment: `$('#galleria1, #galleria2').each(function(i){ /* do you stuff with $(this) */ }` ???? Or I don't understand you?

Comment: I think your code could be structured in a way that would better support the flexibility you want. I'll edit my answer in  a second.

Comment: Also just for reference, take a look at the docs for jQuery selectors.  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your `<div>` elements a "class", and have the script apply itself to all elements with that class.

```
<div id="galleria2" class='galleria' interval="1000">
```

Then in the script:

```
$('div.galleria').each(function() {
  // whatever
});
```

<s>You didn't post the JavaScript code so the actuality might be a little different.</s>

*edit* — OK now that the code has been posted, I'd restructure it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.galleria').each(function() {
    var $galleria = $(this), $anchors = $galleria.find('a'), current = 0;

    function slideshow() {
      //Sets all pictures opacity to 0
      $anchor.css({opacity:0.0});
      //Sets the first picture's opacity to 1
      $anchors.eq(0).css({opacity:1.0});
      //Calls the gallery() function to run the slideshow, number gives time till next 'slide' im milliseconds
      setInterval(nextPicture, 1000);
    }

    function nextPicture() {
      var $prev = $anchors.eq(current);

      //If no image hast the class 'show', takes the first picture
      current = (current + 1) % $anchors.length;

      //Get next image, if reached the end of slideshow, starts from the begining
      var next = $anchors.eq(current);

      //Runs Animation and makes next picture visible, number gives fade in time
      next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('show')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

      //Hides last picture
      $prev.animate({opacity: 0.0},1000)
        .removeClass('show');
    }

    slideshow();
});
```

By nesting the functions inside the ".each()" iterator, they'll operate on their own assigned "galleria" instance.

Comment: If I use a class instead of an id, don't I have the exact problem again, that they all do the same?

Comment: Well let me take a look at the code, now that it's been posted.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is use the multiple ids selector: `$("#galleria1,#galleria2").Slider();`